# How to specify a start point on highcharts stacked bar charts

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

I have datetime values on y-axis and I am trying to start my values in 2019 however, highcharts defaults to a datetime of 0 which is around 1970. So I have to include an initial column that brings me to todays date. How do I get round this and start adding my time values to a value that isn't 0?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `threshold` property:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ...
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        threshold: threshold
    }
},
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7vgkm3y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold